# How to select an item in MVCxGridLookup in jQuery, when page loads

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress

I get a value in a model, but how do I set that value as the selected value in an MVCxGridLookup control in jQuery? I am able to set it in PreRender() method for the control. But now I need to do it in jQuery.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution !

`$("#DropdownList").val('@Model.Name');` **-->this is wrong.**

This^ was what I was doing before, but it wont work. 'DropdownList' was the name I gave for the GridLookup control, but the id will vary from this, because this is a DevExpress control.

When we inspect the page elements (using developer tools or just right click and inspect element), the actual id it was assigned can be found.

`$("#DropdownList_I").val('@Model.Name');` **-->this solved the problem.**